# How to remove nested structure of containers inside content panel

Tags: pdfbox

[image: nested structure]

Hi everyone!
Please look into above image, inside content panel there are four paragraph containers which
coming like nested way i.e one inside another. So , Is there any way to convert into like this
[image: expecting output]

So please anyone can help. Thanks in advance.